# How to run a time series model based on select seasonal data only

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

I have a time series dataset for electricity load demand as follows:

```
datetime                       load
2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00   483.52698
2017-01-01 00:05:00+00:00   480.69008
2017-01-01 00:10:00+00:00   480.28880
2017-01-01 00:15:00+00:00   478.72021
2017-01-01 00:20:00+00:00   476.37618
... ...
2021-08-30 22:40:00+00:00   951.17640
2021-08-30 22:45:00+00:00   946.24726
2021-08-30 22:50:00+00:00   940.98128
2021-08-30 22:55:00+00:00   935.02204
2021-08-30 23:00:00+00:00   929.44998
```

The data is by 5 min increments.  Instead of running a traditional SARIMA model accounting for the seasonality (monthly), I'd like to instead run 2 seperate time series models, 1 for summer and 1 for winter, so for example the summer time series model would only look at data from Jun-YEAR - Aug-YEAR.  This data would not be continuous in that the final day in August would be followed by June 1st of the next year.

Thus would I have to re-index the data? I'm not clear how to account for this when only comparing certain months in a time series and having the gap from end of the final month to beginning of start month of the following year (ex: 8/31/2019, 6/1/2020).